# Is it possible to point a local instance IIS to a shared windows file server as the home directory?

Tags: .net, iis, localhost, shared-directory

I'm just beginning work with IIS, .NET, etc. so I apologize if any of this is unclear. I recently installed a local instance of IIS and it's up and running just fine. I'm wondering if it's possible to point IIS to a shared windows folder that exists on another server, and have that folder serve as the root directory for IIS. Is this at all possible? If so, can anyone point me to a resource explaining how to do this?

One thing to note is that the shared folder requires authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the IIS Admin console go to the website properties and look at the 'Home Directory' tab. You can specify 'A share located on another computer'. When you choose this you will also see a 'Connect As' button next to the 'Network Directory' field.